# Ruby Cucumber Framework - Fig Newton Gem not redirecting to environment url when running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automation, rubygems, cucumber

Trying to parameterize environments for the Ruby Cucumber framework. When I run the test, the browser appears but does not redirect to the url in the yml file. This is what I've done so far:

- I put fig_newton in the gemfile and ran a bundle install
- In the config directory, I have an environments directory containing a qa.yml file.
- In the qa.yml file I have something like base_url: www.google.com
- In the cucumber.yml file I have qa: FIG_NEWTON_FILE=qa.yml --no-source --color --format pretty
- On my page class, I have something like:

  ```
  class LoginPage
  include PageObject
  include FigNewton

  page_url FigNewton.base_url
  ```
- In my step definitions I have:
      Given("I am on the login page") do
      visit_page(LoginPage)
      end
- My runner options have (I'm using Rubymine IDE): --color -p qa

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the qa.yml file. In your `env.rb` insert this line of code -

`FigNewton.load('qa.yml')`